# jQuery slide appear and disappear in same button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In clicking the `Slide toggle` button, the two div, slides in two opposite direction. I want to,  Clicking in the same button, to make them appear again, how can i do it? Below is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slide-toggle").click(function(){            
        $(".box .left").css( {
            "-webkit-transform" : "translateX(-100%) " ,
            "transform": "translateX(-100%)",
            "transition": "all 1s ease-out"
        });
        $(".box .right").css( {
            "-webkit-transform" : "translateX(100%) " ,
            "transform": "translateX(100%)",
            "transition": "all 1s ease-out"
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/perseverance/xpvt214o/967767/)

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnkj69ar/).**

You could use flag variable (`visible` in my example) then toggle the value from true/false and using this flag toggle the value of `transform`, like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var visible = true;

  $(".slide-toggle").click(function() {
    var translate = visible ? 100 : 0;

    $(".box .left").css({
      "-webkit-transform": "translateX(-" + translate + "%) ",
      "transform": "translateX(-" + translate + "%)",
      "transition": "all 1s ease-out"
    });
    $(".box .right").css({
      "-webkit-transform": "translateX(" + translate + "%) ",
      "transform": "translateX(" + translate + "%)",
      "transition": "all 1s ease-out"
    });
    visible = translate === 100 ? false : true;
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f0e68c;
}


/* Add padding and border to inner content
    for better animation effect */

.box-inner {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #a29415;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="slide-toggle">Slide Toggle</button>
  <hr>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. eger aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. eger aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy and straight forward solution would be to toggle a class on the `box` element.

This means adding a class when you first click the button, add some styles to the `left` and `right` elements, and then remove the class so the elements return to their original positions.

Check below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slide-toggle").click(function(){
             $(".box").toggleClass('go-away')
                 
        });
    });
```

```css
.box{
        float:left;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #f0e68c;

    }
    /* Add padding and border to inner content
    for better animation effect */
    .box-inner{
        width: 400px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #a29415;
        transition:all 1s ease-out;
    }
   .box.go-away .left {
     transform:translateX(-100%) 
   }
    .box.go-away .right {
     transform:translateX(100%) 
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" class="slide-toggle">Slide Toggle</button>
    <hr>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-inner left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. eger aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-inner right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. eger aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RubelAhmed glad i could help. if this answer solved your problem please don't forget to rate and/or accept it. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slide-toggle").click(function(){
            // $(".box").animate({
            //     width: "toggle"
            // });
            if($(".box .left").hasClass("out")){
                $(".box .left").removeClass("out");
              $(".box .left").css( {
                "-webkit-transform" : "translateX(0%) " ,
                "transform": "translateX(0%)",
                "transition": "all 1s ease-in"
            });
            $(".box .right").css( {
                "-webkit-transform" : "translateX(0%) " ,
                "transform": "translateX(0%)",
                "transition": "all 1s ease-in"
            });
            } else{
            $(".box .left").addClass("out");
            $(".box .left").css( {
                "-webkit-transform" : "translateX(-100%) " ,
                "transform": "translateX(-100%)",
                "transition": "all 1s ease-out"
            });
            $(".box .right").css( {
                "-webkit-transform" : "translateX(100%) " ,
                "transform": "translateX(100%)",
                "transition": "all 1s ease-out"
            });
            }      
        });
    });
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/970174/)